# run Scala in TextMate

Tags: scala, textmate, textmatebundles

I am trying to run Scala in TextMate. I have created a new variable TM_SCALA and set it to the path which I obtained on executing the following command on the terminal

```
which scala
```

But when I try to run a Scala program, I get the error

```
Run Script: line 4: scala: command not found
```

This is the run script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh" ]] && . "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh"

scala -classpath . -savecompiled "$TM_FILEPATH"
```

I am unable to understand the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you have scala downloaded.
2. update PATH variable in TextMate preferences. Append scalac path there.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a new command (or replace the 'run script' one) with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

cmd = ENV['SCALA_HOME'] + "/scala -nocompdaemon -howtorun:script '" + ENV['TM_FILEPATH'] + "'"

result = "" + `#{cmd}`

puts "#{result}"
```

That assumes that you have a SCALA_HOME environment variable set to something like this:

```
export SCALA_HOME="/path/to/my/scala/scala-2.11.4/"
```